# Java.lang.NullPointerException por causa de uma lista

Tags: java

Bom, estou estudando java e estava vendo composição, então decidi fazer algumas coisas:

> **Visâo geral do sistema** : Deseja-se fazer um sistema de cadastro de contas bancárias, e cada conta possui nome do titular, senha, número
>   da conta e saldo. Os "usuários" devem poder fazer log-in que consiste
>   em nome e senha já cadastrados, para acessar funcionalidades de sua
>   conta. Após o log-in deve ser dado as operações de depósito, saque e
>   transferência(...)
>
> Neste programa contém três classes, Conta, Login e Operacao. Conta é
>   independente e a base do programa, Login é uma associação de Conta e
>   Operacao é uma associação de Login e Conta.

Na classe Conta foi declarado uma lista como sendo um de seus atributos (não sei se foi a escolha correta, parametrizar uma lista com a própria classe em que ela está inserida), e a função dela é cadastrar as contas na lista que está dentro dela com nome do titular, senha, número da conta e saldo. E a do Login tem a única função de validar um nome e senha passado, ver se na lista tem alguma posição que contenha esse nome e senha passado e se positivo informar qual a posição atribuindo o número da posição correta a um de seus atributos que se chama logado, para depois a classe operação saber com quem ela pode interagir.

O problema está na validação, o método `public void validacao(String nome, int senha)` utiliza um `for` dentro dele que percorre (ou deveria) toda a lista validando o nome e senha informado com nomes e senhas já cadastrados, para ver se bate e se existe. Só que quando ele vai fazer isso já rodando no main dá o erro `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` como se ele estivesse buscando posições nulas na lista (mesmo "tendo" várias). Acredito eu rsrs.

Vou passar o código do main até a parte que dá o erro e o código das classes Conta e Login, Operacao não precisa pois ele nem chegou até ela devido a esse problema.

```
   package application1;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

import entities1.Conta;
import entities1.Login;
import entities1.Operacao;

public class ProgramContaBancaria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Por favor, faça o cadastro:");

        boolean check = false;
        while(check == false) {
            System.out.println("Digite o nome da conta para cadastro: ");
            String nome = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Digite a senha da conta para cadastro: ");
            int senha = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Digite o número da conta para cadastro: ");
            int numeroDaConta = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Digite o saldo inicial da conta para cadastro: ");
            double saldo = sc.nextDouble();

            Conta conta = new Conta(nome, senha, numeroDaConta, saldo);
            conta.addConta(conta);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Deseja cadastrar mais alguma conta ? (yes/no): ");
            String resposta = sc.next();

            if(resposta.equals("yes")) {
                check = false;
            }
            else if (resposta.equals("no")) {
                check = true;
            }   
        }

        System.out.println("Conta(s) cadastradas com sucesso!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Entre com nome e senha para efetuar o login: ");
        System.out.print("Nome: ");
        String nome = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Senha: ");
        int senha = sc.nextInt();

        Login login = new Login();
        login.validacao(nome, senha);

        System.out.println("Bem-Vindo "+login.getNome()+", o que deseja fazer ?");
        System.out.println("Depósito $ (digite 1)");
        System.out.println("Saque $ (digite 2)");
        System.out.println("Transferência $ (digite 3)");
        int escolha = sc.nextInt();

        Operacao operacao = new Operacao();
        switch (escolha) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Quanto quer depositar ?");
            double valorDeposito = sc.nextDouble();
            operacao.deposito(valorDeposito);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Quanto quer sacar ?");
            double valorSaque = sc.nextDouble();
            operacao.saque(valorSaque);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Informe o valor da transferência e a conta para qual quer transferir");
            System.out.print("Valor: ");
            double valorTransferencia = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Conta: ");
            int numeroDaContaTransferir = sc.nextInt();
            operacao.transferencia(valorTransferencia, numeroDaContaTransferir);
            break;
        }
        sc.close();


    }

}
```

Classe conta

```
package entities1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Conta {

    private String nome;
    private Integer senha;
    private Integer numeroDaConta;
    private Double saldo;

    private List<Conta> contas = new ArrayList<>();

    public Conta() {

    }

    public Conta(String nome, Integer senha, Integer numeroDaConta, Double saldo) {     
        this.nome = nome;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.numeroDaConta = numeroDaConta;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(Integer senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Integer getNumeroDaConta() {
        return numeroDaConta;
    }

    public void setNumeroDaConta(Integer numeroDaConta) {
        this.numeroDaConta = numeroDaConta;
    }

    public Double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(Double saldo) {
        this.saldo += saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo1(Double saldo) {
        this.saldo -= saldo;
    }

    public List<Conta> getContas() {
        return contas;
    }

    public void addConta(Conta conta) {
        contas.add(conta);
    }

    public void removeConta(Conta conta) {
        contas.remove(conta);
    }



}
```

Classe login

```
package entities1;

public class Login {

    private String nome;
    private Integer senha;
    private Integer logado;

    private Conta conta;


    public Login() {
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public Integer getLogado() {
        return logado;
    }

    public Conta getConta() {
        return conta;
    }

    public void validacao(String nome, int senha) {
        for (int i = 0; i < conta.getContas().size(); i++) {
            if (conta.getContas().get(i).getNome().equals(nome) && conta.getContas().get(i).getSenha().equals(senha)) {
                logado += i;
                this.nome = nome;
                this.senha = senha;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A primeira classe está incompleta.

Comment: Fiquei interessado no problema, poderia colocar a descrição inteira do mesmo? Também para ajudar na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem 2 problemas.

1 - Você cria um novo objeto Conta dentro de um loop `while` que nunca é usado.

```
while(check == false) {
...
Conta conta = new Conta(nome, senha, numeroDaConta, saldo);
conta.addConta(conta);
```

Ou seja, você não criou uma lista de contas. Você apenas instanciou uma nova conta e inseriu em uma lista dentro do objeto criado cada vez que o bloco foi chamado. E que depois desaparece quando o loop é finalizado.

2 - O que parece é que você gostaria de usar essa lista dentro do objeto login. Só que a conta não foi setada ao objeto login, logo, ela continua nula.

**Solução**

Uma solução prática que você pode implementar sem alterar muito o que você fez é o seguinte:

**Classe Conta**

Altere o atributo da lista de Contas para estático assim:

```
private static List<Conta> contas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Altere as funções abaixo também:

```
    public static List<Conta> getContas() {
        return contas;
    }

    public static void addConta(Conta conta) {
        contas.add(conta);
    }

    public static void removeConta(Conta conta) {
        contas.remove(conta);
    }
```

Agora, para usar, você terá que alterar as outras partes assim:

No `while` do metodo main:

```
        Conta conta = new Conta(nome, senha, numeroDaConta, saldo);
        Conta.addConta(conta); // <-- aqui com letra maiuscula
```

Na sua classe Login troque tudo isso:

```
conta.getContas() // <-- letra minuscula
```

Por isso:

```
Conta.getContas() // <-- letra maiuscula
```

**O que eu fiz acima**

Eu alterei todos os métodos e atributos que dependiam de instancias (Objetos) para métodos e atributos estáticos. Assim, eles passam a pertencer à Classe e não ao Objeto, sendo assim, você não precisará setá-los em cada instância.